# Clipping images or blowing up images in vb.net

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, clipping

I have created an image upload program that allows the user to crop the images and then when loads the images on a template brochure but I'm having an issue with either programatically picking up if the image needs either to centered in the box or if it can somewhat clip the image or blow up the image if they cropped the image to small.

here is the code for the size and position of the background image:

```
// Size and position background image 595/516
                var $bgImg = $(".bgImg img");
                if ($bgImg.length == 1) {
                    var bgImg = $bgImg[0];
                    var w = bgImg.width;
                    var h = bgImg.height;

                    var divRatio = 595/516;
                    var imgRatio = w/h;

                    var w1, h1, factor = 1;
                    if (divRatio < imgRatio) {
                        factor = h / 516;
                    }
                    else {
                        factor = w / 595;
                    }

                    w1 = w * factor;
                    h1 = h * factor;
                    alert(w1 + " x " + h1);
                }
```

I'm not 100% sure to it exactly as I am at the moment am getting a big number and I just need a specific number. ANy help would be appricated.

Comment: What does this have to do with VB.NET?  Shouldn't JavaScript be tagged on this?

Comment: The only reason I had it tagged as vb.net was because its a combination of the 2 both javascript and the other uploading part is done with vb.net